# How to find an algorithm to find a point in a row that has a lower distance with others?

Tags: algorithm

Imagine that we have n city in one row with the same distance and each of them has a population, we want to build a post office, and we want to choose a city that most people have to take a less route to that office, how to find the city?

The user should input the cities number(n) and their population and got the city that the post office should be built.

This is the example that was in the problem and I don't know why it has this result:

```
6 (number of cities (n))

3 1 0 0 2 2  (populations)      ---->       2  (the city number 2 that have a 1 population)
```

The thing that I'm looking for is an algorithm or a formula to find the city, not the code. Any idea?

Comment: Why can't you understand the given example? Have you tried working it out?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur i tried to make a ratio between the population and the distance they have to travel and i belive the city number 5 could be a better choice but I'm not sure that i do it in right way

Comment: The ratio won't be used for comparison. Sum of distance travelled by each person in each town will be used

Comment: @AbhinavMathur actually i meant that too, i add a distance that each person will travel for example in 1st city 3 people will travel one x and in 5th city 2 people will travel 3x and so on

Comment: city 2 and 5 would both give a distance of 17, either can be used as an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you work out your example, you'll see a simple pattern. Let's say the total distance for index `i` is `x`. If we move to index `i+1`,

1. All cities in range [0, i] will now become further away from the post office by 1 unit.
2. All cities in range [i+1, n] will now become closer to the post office by 1 unit.

Using the example you have provided (assuming 0 based indexing):

1. Let the office be at index 1. Current total distance: `3 + (2*3) + (2*4) = 17`
2. Let's shift it to index 2. Increase in distance for the cities on left of index 2 = `3+1=4`. Decrease in distance for cities on the right = `2+2=4`.

Simply put, if we move from index `i` to `i+1`,

```
new_distance = old_distance + sum(array[j] for j in range [0,i]) - sum(array[j] for j in range [i+1,n])
```

To make it more efficient, `sum(array[j] for j in range [0,i])` is nothing but [prefix sum](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/prefix-sum-array-implementation-applications-competitive-programming/). You can calculate that in one pass, then solve the distances for each city in another pass. That `O(N)` time and space complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's mean that if the office will be on either index 1,2,3,4 the distance won't change, also cities on index 2,3 has a lower population so cities on 1,4 will be a better choice because more people have to travel less, this is why I believe city 4 is a better choice because of more population.

Comment: @Roxana why wouldn't the distance change for indexes 1,2,3,4? Have you tried working this out?

Comment: i do this :
if the office is on index 1 so 3 people have to travel 1x so `3x` and 2 people have to travel 3x so `6x` and also 2 people will travel 4x so` 8x` and if we add them together we have `17x` if we do it for another index we have 17 for cities on 1,2,3,4.
also, if we do it as you said and shift i to i + 1 and calculate the distance for cities that increase and those that decrease; we'll have a zero in 1,2,3,

Comment: Use a different example and work this algo out on that, let me know if this still feels wrong